# Is there a user specific equivalent to /etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, networking

Is there some way to define user specific hosts - like in /etc/hosts?
Maybe something like ~/.hosts?

Comment: can you tell what you are actually wanting to do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For anything ssh based (including rsync over ssh) you can add entries to your ~/.ssh/config file

e.g.

```
Host myhost
    Hostname myhost.example.com
```

Then ssh myhost will connect you to myhost.example.com

Comment: add a "User" option and It's a great recipe for heterogenous systems.

Comment: I use this approach with wildcards and bash completion for hostnames with the HOSTFILE environment variable.  I end up with tab-completion of the 'alternate' hostnames quite nicely.

Comment: You can also use this to do cool stuff with Git, if you have multiple keys or accounts you need to use. You can set up path-based conditional config in Git, and use SSH settings to specify users/keys as needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801729/is-it-possible-to-have-different-git-configuration-for-different-projects

Answer (score 5):

Specific applications may have something you can use, like Nick suggested, but there is no user homedir equivelent of the /etc/hosts file.

When applications try to resolve hostnames it gets handled by NSS. You can check how NSS handles hostnames on your system by looking at /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
$ grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:          files dns
```

This means that hostnames will be resolved first against the file database (/etc/hosts), and failing that against the dns details specified in /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering the same thing and a colleague found this solution: http://blog.tremily.us/posts/HOSTALIASES/

It basically involves setting an environment variable (HOSTALIASES) which points to the file to use for host aliases (you could use ~/.hosts for example).

Comment: The link broke :-(

Comment: Currently, the link works (again).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be different "chroot" environments for different users. Even different root jails for same user, depending on certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://github.com/bAndie91/libnss_homehosts referenced in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266445

That we you could have ~/.hosts file, with same syntax as /etc/hosts has.

Comment: Not an universal solution (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104511/79008)).